# Does $P^g=\{gpg^{-1}|g \in G\}$ have the same order as P, where |P|=7

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Say we have a group G, s.t P is a subgroup of G and |G|=28,|P|=7. then consider $P^g=\{gpg^{-1}|g \in G\}$ what is the order of this group ? I think that it is seven as well because if we consider the fact that the order of an element must divide the order of the group then we realise that the order of the elements must be seven or 1. it's not one as the group is too large for that so it is seven.

then if we take $(gpg^{-1})^7$ we get $(gpg^{-1})(gpg^{-1})(gpg^{-1})(gpg^{-1})(gpg^{-1})(gpg^{-1})(gpg^{-1})=gp^7g^{-1}=gg^{-1}=1$

Is this correct ?

Comment: Here, is $p$ fixed? And where does it come from?

Comment: p is just one of the elements from our subgroup P.

Comment: Your notation and description for $P^g$ is not compatible. If $p$ is fixed and $G$ is abelian then by your notation $P^g$ has only one element.

Comment: First, I think you are confused. $P^g$ should be $\{gpg^{-1}\mid p\in P\}$ and not what you describe, since the notation has single $g$ but your description has a single $p$, that is undefined. Second, your calculation of $(gpg^{-1})^7$ is correct, but it does not show that $gPg^{-1}$ has order $7$; after all, $C_7\times C_7$ has order $49$, but still satisfies $x^7=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Instead, to show that if $X$ is any subset of $G$, then $X^g = \{gxg^{-1}\mid x\in X\}$ has the same number of elements as $X$, show that $gxg^{-1}$ is equal to $gyg^{-1}$ if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: (Finally, the notation you are choosing is bad; $P^g$ should be the set of all $g^{-1}pg$, not the set of all $gpg^{-1}$; because the way you’ve defined it, $(P^g)^h$ is not equal to $P^{gh}$. )

Comment: ahh thank you I see where my notation is incorrect now. would you mind explaining how one could find the order of P^g. It's part of a larger proof that P is a normal subgroup which works fine if P has the same size as $P^g$, but otherwise I'm not sure how to prove it .

Comment: sorry I typed that out before I saw your reply. ah so you say prove that the function from P to P^g is injective . makes sense.... thank you :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you meant that $P^g=\{gxg^{-1} \, | \, x \in P\}$ (also called the conjugate subgroup of $P$ via $g$.)

Let $g \in G$ be fixed and define $f:P \to G$ as $f(x)=gxg^{-1}$. Then this map is one-one, because 
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=f(y)\\
gxg^{-1} & =gyg^{-1}\\
x&=y && (\text{left and right cancellation})
\end{align*}

Since the map is injective, therefore $|P|=|\text{Image}_f|=|P^g|$.